# How do I use ThemeData backgroundColor to get Colors.blue[100]?

Tags: flutter

How do I use ThemeData backgroundColor to get Colors.blue[100]?

I think that I have read all that there is on this subject, but it does not appear to solve my problem. I don't want to use hex colors.

In "main", I've defined the background color as follows:

```
 theme: ThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
```

In a program where I want to use this, I've defined the MaterialColor and assigned a value as follows:

```
MaterialColor _bgColor;
...
_bgColor = Theme.of(widget.context).backgroundColor;
```

This works as expected.

However, what I want to use as the color is Colors.blue[100].
If I specify that as follows:

```
 theme: ThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
        ),
```

then I get the run-time error -  type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor'.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import MaterialColor

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Comment: No, I already have that and need it just to compile. Colors.blue[100] cannot be used in ThemeData, but there must be a way to get it (I presume) and that is what I need to know.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i found a [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15658#issuecomment-373964562) on how to fix it.

summary
Looks like this is working as intended:

`primarySwatch` takes a `ColorSwatch` which `MaterialColor extends.` A swatch is a map of shades for a color (`from [50] to [900]`).

`Colors.tea`l is a swatch, it includes all the different Color variations of teal, of which `teal[100]` is just one.

`Colors.teal[100]` is an individual Color, it can't be assigned to a property that expects a full swatch.

Comment: OK, so I specify the Theme Color as Colors.blue as I did in my first example above. How then do I get blue[100] from that which is what I want to do?

Comment: backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100], material color